# How to use Windows Command Line to search for file, then create text document with location?

Tags: windows, file, search, command-line

I'm writing my first batch file, and as I've never used Windows Command Line before, I'm running into some issues.

Here's my scenario. I use this batch file on several images to install something. I want the batch file to check the folder that the installer SHOULD be in, and if it's not there, I want the batch file to search the computer for the installer. After that, I want it to run said installer.

Here's what I have:

```
ECHO.
ECHO Starting Foo installation

IF EXIST Install\Installer.cmd (CALL Install\Installer.cmd & GOTO NextPart) ELSE (GOTO SearchInstaller)

:SearchInstaller
SET the_path =
E: & CD\
DIR /S/B Installer.cmd > installer_location.txt
IF EXIST installer_location.txt (SET /P the_path =< installer_location.txt & GOTO FoundIt)
C: & CD\
DIR /S/B Installer.cmd > installer_location.txt
IF EXIST installer_location.txt (SET /P the_path =< installer_location.txt & GOTO FoundIt)
D: & CD\
DIR /S/B Installer.cmd > installer_location.txt
IF EXIST installer_location.txt (SET /P the_path =< installer_location.txt & GOTO FoundIt)
ECHO Installation file not found.

:FoundIt
ECHO Batch file found at%the_path%
CALL %the_path%
ECHO Finished installation & ECHO. 
GOTO NextPart

:NextPart
(more stuff)
```

I think the problem is that it isn't saving the path, once I use DIR to locate it. I've been researching for days, and my Google searches are all full of purple links. Everything I find says my syntax is right, but I know I'm doing something wrong.

I've tried placing an `ECHO Program execution reached this point.` in several spots, so I know where it does get to, at least. The problems I'm seeing are with the line that assigns the text file's contents to `the_path` and in the line where I'm trying to `ECHO` the path, so I can see it worked.

Comment: I would say that as soon as you had any non-trivial if or ANY loop stop using a batch file. I started learning python for just this kind of thing. Or pick any other (non-powershell :-) script (it might work with msbuild), you'll be happier and more productive for it

Comment: I would love to (I adore Python), but I'm stuck with batch for the moment.

Comment: I don't think this will find the `cmd` file on the `C:` or `D:` drives because` installer_location.txt` will always exist (but be empty) after failing to find the file on the `E:` drive.

Comment: !!   That could be a problem... I was under the assumption that if it didn't find the file, it didn't create the .txt

Comment: Could I - instead of checking to see if the text got created - check to see the size of the text file, and test it against 0? Can command-speak do that?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include what will hopefully be a solution to this issue.

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you! I'd upvote you twice for that, if I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `SET /P` commands, you've got a space between the variable name and the equals sign.  This does exactly what you're asking it to, rather than what you wanted: it sets a variable whose name ends in a space.  Get rid of the extra spaces and I think it will work.

Additional:-

To avoid the problem Neil pointed out (good catch!) try this:

```
DIR /S/B Installer.cmd > installer_location.txt
SET /P the_path=< installer_location.txt
if defined the_path goto :foundit
```

It turns out that if `installer.cmd` isn't found, `installer_location.txt` is empty and `the_path` doesn't get defined.  If you want to be extra careful, try

```
if defined the_path if exist "%the_path%" goto :foundit
```